# there is any way to reduce code to update multiple columns in mysql python?

Tags: python, mysql

there is any way to reduce code to update multiple columns in mysql python ?
im new in python and mysql

```
    mycursor.execute("""UPDATE AVAX_position SET stoplossexcude=%s WHERE name=%s""",
                     ('false', 'aiposition'))
    mycursor.execute("""UPDATE ETH_position SET stoplossexcude=%s WHERE name=%s""",
                     ('false1', 'aiposition'))
    mycursor.execute("""UPDATE ETH_position SET openorder=%sWHERE name=%s""",
                     ('false', 'aiposition'))
    mycursor.execute("""UPDATE ADA_position SET openorder=%sWHERE name=%s""",
                     ('false', 'aiposition'))
    mycursor.execute("""UPDATE DOGE_position SET openorder=%sWHERE name=%s""",
                     ('false', 'aiposition'))
    mycursor.execute("""UPDATE BNB_position SET openorder=%sWHERE name=%s""",
                     ('false', 'aiposition'))
    mycursor.execute("""UPDATE UNI_position SET openorder=%sWHERE name=%s""",
                     ('false', 'aiposition'))
    mycursor.execute("""UPDATE MATIC_position SET openorder=%sWHERE name=%s""",
                     ('false', 'aiposition'))
```

Comment: you can join the table and update all in one, but the code woll get much more complicated

Comment: These statements all update different tables (except for ETH_position which appears twice).  There's no easy compact way to update multiple tables at once.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't have all these different tables in the first place. Have a single `position` table with a `currency` column that can contain values like `AVAX`, `ETH`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop with all the currency types.

```
for currency in ['AVAX', 'ADA', 'DOGE', 'BNB', 'UNI', 'MATIC']:
    mycursor.execute(f"""UPDATE {currency}_position SET stoplossexcude=%s WHERE name=%s""",
        ('false', 'aiposition'))
# This one has a differentvalue of stoplossexclude, so do it separately
mycursor.execute("""UPDATE ETH_position SET stoplossexcude=%s WHERE name=%s""",
    ('false1', 'aiposition'))
```